# Outlook Vba Code gives an error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Calendar") 'active worksheet
    wks.Cells(NextRow, 1) = ComboBox1.Value
```

I have this two lines of code with me. Here it gives me an `error number 1004` when I am going to assign the value of combobox to the worksheet's(wks) first cell.
Let me know some resolution....

Advance Thanks....

Comment: I'd suggest that you look closely at the value of NextRow. If it's 0 I would expect that you will get a 1004 error.

Comment: Kindly debug and check the value of variable NextRow and wkb.

Comment: Thanks Alan and Santosh.....Its awesome resolution by both of you...

Comment: @mon Kindly 'close' the questions by marking correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

Runtime Error 1004 usually means that you are referring to an object that does not exist in your workbook.

As in your case  `wks.Cells(NextRow, 1) = ComboBox1.Value` 
check the value of variable NextRow and make sure its greater than 0 to avoid the issue.

Also check wks workbook is valid workbook object.

[image]

Comment: + 1  I believe that is the reason :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue may occur if either of the following conditions is true:

- The Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) macro copies and pastes one whole row in an Excel 2003 workbook.
- The Microsoft VBA macro copies and pastes a range of 2,516 rows or more rows in an Excel 2003 workbook.

The Runtime error 1004 means:

```
Runtime error 1004: Paste method of worksheet class failed.
Runtime error 1004: Copy method of Range Class Failed.
```

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905164