# Adding Cell Value to an Integer (Excel-VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

With years of programming experience (beginner with VBA, however), online references, and search engines I'm yet frustrated to the utmost with my inability to get this to work.

I've spent at least two hours trying every combination of CInt, .Range, With/End With, .Value, Cells, etc. that I could possibly think of and it just keeps failing on the "sum = sum + ..." line:

```
Public Sub Fill_InnerData()

    Dim GNumber As Range
    Set GNumber = Range("GenerateNumber")

    Dim Data As Range
    Set Data = Range("DATA_INNER")

    For r = 1 To Data.Rows.Count

        For c = 1 To Data.Columns.Count
    
            If Data.Cells(r, c) = "" Then
            
                If c > r Then
            
                    Data.Cells(r, c) = 0
            
                Else
                    Dim x As Integer
                    x = r - c + 1
                
                    Dim y As Integer
                    y = 2
            
                    Dim sum As Integer
                    sum = 1
                
                    For i = 1 To c
                        sum = sum + CInt(Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(x, y)).Value)
                        y = y + 1
                    Next
                
                End If
            
            End If

        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

By "failing" I mean getting this error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

I've received that error at the mentioned line with EVERY combination that I tried.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: kindly verify the values in variable x,y. It should should be greater than 0 always.Also worksheet with name "Data" must exist.

Comment: Worksheet "Data" definitely exists as this sub is in a module with another sub which sets values in "Data" and that sub works perfectly.  Also, good catch with checking the X and Y values as the line "x = r - c" should have been "x = r - c + 1" (now updated).  This, however, has not changed the resulting error message in the slightest.

Comment: Runtime Error 1004 usually means that you are referring to an object that does not exist in your workbook. You may refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053948/outlook-vba-code-gives-an-error-1004/16054109#16054109

Comment: Try CInt(Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, y).Value)

Comment: @android_newbie
I did try that (as well as many many other combinations) and it did not work.  KazJaw's answer indicates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The think here is with your syntax referring to range. It should be enough to cut it a bit and do it this way:

```
Sum = Sum + CInt(Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, y).Value)
```

According to my experiences range requires address string inside parenthesis if only one argument is provided. Or you can put Cells if you provide both starting and ending range points. This two simple lines has correct syntax:

```
Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(2,2)).Select
Range(Cells(1,1).Address).Select
```

This is not valid:

```
Range(Cells(1,1)).Select    'error 1004 here
```